# C# String Manipulation: From "TABLE_NAME" to "TableName"

Tags: c#, string

The best way to do this?

Tried things like that:

```
public String FormatColumnName(String columnName)
{
    String formatedColumnName = columnName.Replace('_', ' ').Trim();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(formatedColumnName);
    result[0] = char.ToUpper(result[0]);
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Didn't work for me, maybe someone could give me a clean Solution on how I can do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
string result = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(
       columnName.Replace('_', ' ').Trim().ToLower()).Replace(" ","");
```

`ToTitleCase` changes "lower case words" to "Lower Case Words" (but doesn't touch upper case), hence the need to `ToLower` - then we remove the spaces with `Replace`.

Comment: I tried this, result is TABLENAME, I also tried something similiar before, either didnt work

Comment: @eMi I've just tested it and it works fine; please refresh... (I did edit)

Comment: I guess it's right but .Trim() will not remove ' ' in the middle of the string, so the whitespace should be replaced.

Comment: @matheusrufca not for one moment did I suggest it *would*; it will, however, work fine with "table name" to "TableName"

Answer (score 5):

`String.Concat(columnName.Split('_').Select(s => s[0] + s.Substring(1).ToLower()))`

Comment: @eMi, It's not just working, it's a lot more readable. and **maybe** more efficient

Comment: may be, but since I am not so versed with LINQ, I prefer Marc's version.

Answer (score 2):

```
string str = "TABLE_NAME";

string str2 = string.Join("", str.Split('_').Select(p => char.ToUpper(p[0]) + p.Substring(1).ToLower()));
```